# Display the return value from a function to a text box

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to code a calculator that asks you to input two numbers and then pick one of four operations(+,-,/,*) which then displays the result. The problem I'm having is when the answer is returned(From the JS function) how do I get it to display the answer here `Total : <input type="number" id="answer" />"` in my HTML?

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>CALCULATOR</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />


  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>


    First Number : <input type="numbers" id="fnum" /><br /><br />
    Second Number : <input type="numbers" id="snum" /><br /><br />

    Operation? :
    <select id="operation">
      <option value="1">+</option>
      <option value="2">-</option>
      <option value="3">/</option>
      <option value="4">*</option> </select
    ><br /><br />

    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" /><br /><br />

    Total : <input type="number" id="answer" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function calculate() {

  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnum").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("snum").value);

  var o= document.getElementById("#operation");
  var operation = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;


  if (operation == 1) {
    var answer = num1 + num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else if (operation == 2) {
    var answer = num1 - num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else if (operation == 3) {
    var answer = num1 / num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else {
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    return answer;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please take note that despite their similar names, Java and Javascript are two completely different programming languages and not interchangeable. Since it looks like your question is purely about html and Javascript I would remove the Java tag.

Comment: You need to get operation object by document.getElementById("operation") and you need to set result to answer element from your js function directly. like document.getElementById('answer').value = answer;

Answer (score 0):

similar like you got values from imput elements.
try to put code in calucate

document.getElementById("answer").value = answer;

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make your answer variable as `global` here:
Second: After calculating answer all you need to set your answer as input's `value` property.

Like that:

```js
function calculate() {

  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnum").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("snum").value);

  var o= document.getElementById("#operation");
  var operation = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;
  let answer = 0;
  let resultElm = document.getElementById('answer');

  resultElm.input = '';

  if (operation == 1) {
    answer = num1 + num2;
  }
  else if (operation == 2) {
    answer = num1 - num2;
  }
  else if (operation == 3) {
     answer = num1 / num2;
  }
  else {
    answer = num1 * num2;
  }

  resultElm.value = answer
}
```

Hope, This would help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is error at document.getElementById("#operation"), it should be document.getElementById("operation")  without #.

`document.getElementById("name").value= answer`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the result, you can set the HTML element value to the calculated answer:

```js
function calculate() {

  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnum").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("snum").value);

  // Create a reference to the HTML element <input type="number" id="answer" />
  var answerOutput = document.getElementById("answer");

  var o = document.getElementById("#operation");
  var operation = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;

  var answer;
  if (operation == 1) {
    answer = num1 + num2;
  }
  else if (operation == 2) {
    answer = num1 - num2;
  }
  else if (operation == 3) {
    var answer = num1 / num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else {
    answer = num1 * num2;
  }

  // Set the HTML element value with the answer value
  answerOutput.value = answer;
}
```